# parLapply within R6 classes

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r6

I'm looking to use `parLapply()` on windows within an `R6` object and noticed (that in at least some cases) that I do not need to export the R6 functions or data to the nodes.

Here is an example where I can access private methods within `parLapply()`:

```
require(R6);require(parallel)
square <-
R6Class("square",
        public = list(
            numbers = NA,
            squares = NA,
            initialize = function(numbers,integer) {
                self$numbers <- numbers
                squares <- private$square.numbers()
            }
        ),
        private = list(
            square = function(x) {
                return(x^2)
            },
            square.numbers = function() {
                cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
                self$squares <- parLapply(cl,
                                          self$numbers,
                                          function (x) private$square(x)
                                          )
                stopCluster(cl)
            }
        ))
##Test
test <- square$new(list(1,2,3))
print(test$squares)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 9
```

And a second example where I can also access public members:

```
square2 <-
R6Class("square2",
        public = list(
            numbers = NA,
            squares = NA,
            integer = NA,
            initialize = function(numbers,integer) {
                self$numbers <- numbers
                self$integer <- integer
                squares <- private$square.numbers()
            }
        ),
        private = list(
            square = function(x) {
                return(x^2)
            },
            square.numbers = function() {
                cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
                self$squares <- parLapply(cl,
                                          self$numbers,
                                          function (x) private$square(x)+self$integer
                                          )
                stopCluster(cl)
            }
        ))
##Test
test2 <- square2$new(list(1,2,3),2)
print(test2$squares)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 6
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 11
```

My question is twofold: (1) What about R6 makes this possible so that I don't need to export data objects and functions; and (2) can I rely on this behavior or is this an artifact of these specific examples?

**UPDATE:**

This behavior also appears to work using public methods and members after the object has been instantiated:

```
square3 <- R6Class(
    classname = "square3",
    public = list(
        numbers = NA,
        squares = NA,
        integer = NA,
        square = function(x) {
           return(x^2)
        },
        square.numbers = function() {
            cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
            self$squares <- parLapply(cl,
                                      self$numbers,
                                   function (x) self$square(x)+self$integer
                                  )
        stopCluster(cl)
    },
    initialize = function(numbers,integer) {
        self$numbers <- numbers
        self$integer <- integer
    }
    )
)
test3.obj <- square3$new(list(1,2,3),2)
test3.obj$square.numbers()
test3.obj$squares

# [[1]] 
# [1] 3
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 6
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With R6 classes, every time you instantiate an object, that object gets a copy of each function/method, with a modified environment. The functions are assigned an environment where `self` points to the object's public environment (this is the public face of the object), and `private` points to the object's private environment.

This is different from S3 methods, which don't get copied for each instantiation of an object.

In summary: with R6, everything is self-contained in the object; with S3, the object does not contain methods.

I'm not that familiar with using `parLapply`, but I think that it's safe to rely on things working like that with `parLapply`.

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled by this explanation: shouldn’t the same also work with S3, simply because each fork of R gets its own copy of the working set (the OS kernel handles this, not R)? At any rate, I’ve always been using `mclapply` like this (I don’t use `parLapply` or explicit clusters), I’ve never had to export anything.

Comment: It sounds like your working on os x/linux. From my (limited) understanding, on these operating systems the "fork" gets the entire working directory, which doesn't happen on windows. That's why i was so curious about this behavior as it won't require us windows users to export any methods or members (and thus making the parallel implementation much more convenient). Also, i haven't worked much with s3, so I can't comment on its behavior in a similar situation